# hive installation error : URl

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.0.1/libexec/lib/hive-common-2.0.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:516)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D
    at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:202)
    ... 12 more
```

I am getting the above error when I try to run hive.Please let me know why this error is coming 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HDFS site should be modified as below:

```
<name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
<value>/tmp/hive-${user.name}</value>

<name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
<value>/tmp/${user.name}</value>

<name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
<value>/tmp/${user.name}_resources</value>

<name>hive.scratch.dir.permission</name>
<value>733</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are Log4j Lookups then they should be specified as

```
${sys:java.io.tmpdir}/${sys:user.name}
```

instead of

```
${system:java.io.tmpdir}/${system:user.name}
```